# Regular expression to delete XML element names

Tags: regex, xml, wildcard, kettle

I have a situation. In order to develop one quite complex XML, I have used "place-holders". Once my XML is ready, I need to delete those 'place-holders'.

**Sample Input**

```
<consumers>
  <place-holder_1>
    <consumer>
      <val>1</val>
    </consumer>
  </place-holder_1>
  <place-holder_2>
    <consumer-info>
      <val>2</val>
    </consumer-info>
  </place-holder_2>
</consumers>
```

**Sample Output**

```
<consumers>
  <consumer>
    <val>1</val>
  </consumer>
  <consumer-info>
    <val>2</val>
  </consumer-info>
</consumers>
```

Basically, I am looking for a regex which can delete all tags containing anything with "place-holder" in a generic way. Any number between 1 to 10 can be suffix of 'place-holder' tag.

I am struggling to come up with regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/TiWA6l/1) captures the desired nodes

`^\s*<\/?place-holder_\d{1,2}>`

Once captured, you can replace the first capturing group with empty string.

Comment: @cincount. Thanks but it's not deleting <place-holder>val</place-holder>. rest all working fine. I am trying to add '?' after '_' to make it optional but to no avail.

Comment: @CinCount My mistake. I forgot to mention that regex must also delete <place-holder>value</place-holder>, if it occurs. I am trying to add '?' after '_' but to no avail.

Comment: @vikas I see that you have accepted my answer. Did it work for you for the case you mentioned in the comment above?

Comment: @CinCount..With slight change it worked..<\/?place-holder(_)?(\d{1,2})?>

Answer (score 1):

or you can use :

```
(?=(<\/?place-holder_(10|\d)>))
```

you can test it [here!](https://regex101.com/r/u0I8QZ/1)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [XSLT in kettle](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/XSL+Transformation).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity Transform (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying)-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'place-holder')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsh)</kbd>